# Why is the count in this code giving 0, rather than the correct value?

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, count, nsmutablearray

Wondering what I'm missing here. Relatively new to C and iOS development, so please be nice ;-). In `viewController` I've got a NSMutableArray called `_objects` with a changing tableView and thus a changing size of the array. To init my NSMutableArray, I've done this:

```
// viewController.m
     if (!_objects) {
    _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

[_objects insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", x] atIndex:y];
```

My goal is to use `_objects.count` in `calculatorViewController`, so I have done this:

```
// calculatorViewController.m
NSInteger count = viewController._objects.count;
NSLog(@"Count: %i", count);
```

However, upon the log, I get `Count: 0`, even when the count is not zero. What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: can you show me how you are creating viewController instance, seems like you are creating a new instance that's why there is no item in array.

Comment: Very likely what rishi said is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using pushViewController to navigate from viewController to calculatorViewController. If you are doing this then after you create the object of CalculatorViewController, write calculatorViewController.count = [_objects count];

Answer (score -1):

try to use this code...

```
if (_objects) {
   [_objects release];
   _objects = nil;
}
_objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

may this will help you..

Comment: this will flush array every time, while he want to add objects in his array.